# Make system sleep after launchd task completes?

Tags: sleep-wake, launchd, power, automation

I've got a launchd task that runs at 2am every day under my user. I've separately programmed power management to wake up my system at 1:59am so the task will run without any issue. However if the system has to wake to run the task, I would like it to shut down again afterward.

For now my solution is to run `pmset sleepnow` synchronously at the end of the script.

However this means that my system will shut down shortly after 2am, even if I was already actively using it (which can happen).

Is there some way I can conditionally set the system to sleep *only if* the system had to wake in order to run the task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend your launchd task and use [`pmset -g log`](https://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/pmset/) to get a log of all wake events.
I don't have a Mac handy, so cannot check the output of the command, but it has a reason and a timestamp a machine woke up.

You can either assume if a wake event occurred at 01:59 that it was due to power management, or check the wake reason to see if you can derive it from there.
Then you can make the `pmset sleepnow` command conditional on the (derived) wake reason, preventing a sleep even when you're actively using the machine at 02:00.